# GPUImage for iOS - Work with Black & White (blw) preset file

Tags: ios, iphone, image, filter, gpuimage

I can use `GPUImage` in iOS to apply a filter to an image using the following code:

```
NSURL *filter1977      = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle pathForResource:@"1977"      ofType:@"acv"]];
    [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACVURL:filter1977];
```

This is given that I have a 1977.acv Curve file.

My question is: how can I similarly apply a filter to image using a black & white (*.blw) preset file.  What `GPUImage` method can I use for this?